# What is the appropriate role attribute value for the button used for showing a video's time progress - accessibility

Tags: accessibility

In one of the video component, the attribute role="slider" is mentioned in the button tag. The button tag is used to show the time progress of the currently playing video. When fast pass accessibility tool is run when the video is playing, it is showing error on role="slider".

Can anyone suggest the appropriate role value for this video progress timer button ?

Thanks in Advance
S

I am new to accessibility issue fixes and just do not want to try out other roles like "button" in a trial and error manner to resolve the fast pass issue. Instead, would like to understand the appropriate role that can be used on this context.

Comment: If you follow [the MDN doc about slider role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/slider_role), it should be fine. What's the error of your tool ? It's maybe a false positive, or maybe the problem isn't on the slider role itself but on something else.